# Google map static images gives me wrong map type?

Tags: image, google-maps, static

Am I wrong or what?

The Satellite maps should be like this:

[image]

And Hybrid maps should be like this:

[image]

I use this link to get hybrid map:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=170x170&visible=35.7020691%2C139.7753269&key=MYAPIKEY&zoom=18&maptype=hybrid
```

But it gives me this:
[image]

And if I change the type to satellite, it gave me this:
[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BasicMapTypes):

> The following map types are available in the Maps JavaScript API:
>
> - roadmap displays the default road map view. This is the default map type.
> - satellite displays Google Earth satellite images.
> - hybrid displays a mixture of normal and satellite views.
> - terrain displays a physical map based on terrain information.

Your first image is correct, it is a hybrid map (a satellite image with labels).
Your second image is a roadmap.

My guess from the images you posted is you have a typo in your URL (roadmap is the default if you don't provide a type, and what I get if I spell "satelite" [sic] wrong...)